# redirect_to a path stored in a variable does not complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

From several locations i am checking to see if terms of service has been accepted. If not, the user should be redirected to terms of service and then back to where they were going. I don't want to complicate this question by explaining why i am not using 'request.referer'

What i am doing is using session[:return_to] = a path to return to. So... In one controller i have:

```
def index
  if current_user.tos_at.nil?
    session[:return_to] = 'answers path'
    redirect_to terms_of_service_controller_index_path
  end
  ...
end
```

Then after the terms of service are displayed and the user clicks on accept the process is directed to:

def accept_terms_of_service
    current_user.update_attributes(:tos_at => Time.now)
    redirect_to session[:return_to]
  end

Then i am getting:

```
"You are being redirected."
```

After that is printed in the browser, nothing happens. If i change the redirect to:

```
redirect_to answers_path
```

It redirects to the proper path.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign session[:return_to] properly:

```
session[:return_to] = answers_path
```

answers_path is a helper, so when you assign session[:return_to] to a value like 'answers_path', its trying to redirect to a page which located in 'answers_path'.

The second way to do this is not to modify session[:return_to] assign, but to replace

```
redirect_to session[:return_to]
```

with

```
redirect_to send(session[:return_to])
```